# rascal freezes when I am trying to debug a program

Tags: rascal

occassionally, and without a specific pattern, I run into a situation where the rascal interpreter does not proceed with a debugging session. In the progress window, I get the message:

```
Reconnecting importers of affected modules: running command.
```

However, the progress bar remains static. What is causing this to happen? I cannot seem to rid this even if I restart eclipse. It usually starts happening after I start a debug session in a buggy code, then insert a few breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not really a coding question; it may be this is the same UX feedback problem that I've experienced. Since Eclipse Luna and the latest Keppler updates, only when you go into the Debug perspective you see that Rascal is pausing on a breakpoint and the cursor jumps to the right editor. From that view you can then press the Run button to continue finishing the run.

Comment: Yupp. Somehow I failed to notice the pattern!

Comment: will see if we can debug the debugger :-)